# Syntax error: cant assign to operator

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop, syntax-error

```
 def addOp(self):
        i = math.sqrt(-1) 
        addAnswer = (a + b*i) + (c + d*i) = (a + c) + (b + d)*i
        return addAnswer
```

When I run my code it gives me an error on the 'addAnswer' line...
I have tried inputting * when needed and adjusting the parentheses, but no help. Same goes for the code below as well

```
def mutliplicationOp(self):
        multiAnswer =  (a + b*i) * (c + d*i) = (a*c - b*d) + (b*c + a*d)*i
        return multiAnswer
```

Comment: the syntax error is well justified. What do you think it should do? solve the equation?

Comment: i don't understand... what would solving the equation do?

Comment: What do you *expect* `addAnswer` to be? Show the desired output

Comment: if user gives the input as a = 5, b = 6, c= 5 and d=10 and the operator entered is ‘+’,
then the program should print 10 + i16 (Final output).

Comment: and for the multiplication method: If a = 3, b = 2, c = 1 and d = 4, then the program should perform the
following operation: (3 + 2i)*(1 + 4i) = 3 + 12i + 2i + 8i2 = 3 + 14i -8 = -5 + i14 (Final output).
For your reference i2
is considered as -1, so you can simplify the operation as follows:
((a*c) – (b*d)) + i((a*d) + (b*c))

Comment: We still have no idea why the assignment line contains two equals signs or what you hope the semantics of that to be. Really, explain what you want to happen there.

Comment: And don't elaborate down here in the comments - please [edit] your question to be self-contained.

Comment: If you want `True` iff two expressions evaluate to the same value, notice that `c = a == b` uses a single equals sign for assignment, and two for comparison, like in many modern programming languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def addOp(self):
        i = math.sqrt(-1)  # This will create a math domain error though...
        addAnswer = (a + b*i) + (c + d*i) = (a + c) + (b + d)*i
        return addAnswer
```

Why does this have two assignments?  `(a + b*i) + (c + d*i)` and `(a + c) + (b + d)*i` are **equivalent**. You only need one. Same goes for your second piece of code. Just do

```
def addOp(self):
        i = (-1)**0.5
        addAnswer = (a + c) + (b + d)*i
        return addAnswer
```

or even better

```
def addOp(self):
        return (a + c) + (b + d)*1j
```

and similarly for the multiplication part. Alternatively, use the inbuilt `complex` type:

```
def addOp(self):
    return complex(a, b) + complex(c, d)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
def function(c_a, c_b, operation):
    return {'+': c_a.__add__(c_b), 
            '*': c_a.__mul__(c_b), 
            '-': c_a.__sub__(c_b), 
            '/': c_a.__truediv__(c_b)
            }.get(operation, 'Operation "{}" not supported!'.format(operation))
```

Example runs:

```
print(function(complex(2, 2), complex(2, 2), '+'))  # -> (4+4j)
print(function(complex(2, 2), complex(2, 2), '-'))  # -> 0j
print(function(complex(2, 2), complex(2, 2), '*'))  # -> 8j
print(function(complex(2, 2), complex(2, 2), '/'))  # -> (1+0j)
print(function(complex(2, 2), complex(2, 2), '%'))  # -> Operation "%" not supported!
```